# How can I type cast when using the null coalescing operator?

Tags: php, casting, php-7, null-coalescing-operator

Say I have this:

```
$username = (string) $inputs['username'] ?? null;
```

If `$inputs['username']` is set then I want it to cast to `string`. If it's **not** set then `$username` should be `null`.

However, at the moment if `$inputs['username']` is not set it will be an empty string instead of null.

How can I fix this? Or is this intentional behaviour?

Comment: I think what might be happening is that you are casting username which is null, to a string. Then the coalesce operator is seeing the empty string as a value. Therefore the value is set, and it returns the empty string.

Why do you need the string type cast?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was using `??` to cut down on the `isset()` code you'd normally use with `?:` because of working on an application where types need to be strictly enforced.

Comment: Do nullable types solve the problem? `$username = (string?) $inputs['username'] ?? null`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only use the null-coalesce operator if the value you want to return in the non-null case is the same as the value you're testing. But in your case you want to cast it when returning.

So need to use the regular conditional operator and test the value explicitly.

```
$username = isset($input['username']) ? (string) $input['username'] : null;
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I assume that means there's no way around it, i.e. this is just the way it's designed? I was hoping to replace all the `isset()`.

Comment: It can only be used to simplify `isset(expression) ? expression : null`. If it doesn't match that pattern, it won't work.

Answer (score 5):

For my projects I use one of these lines:

```
$array = [
    'a' => 1000
];

$boolA = (bool)($array['a'] ?? false); // bool(true)
$boolB = (bool)($array['b'] ?? false); // bool(false)
$boolC = (bool)($array['c'] ?? false) ?: null; // null

$intA = (int)($array['a'] ?? 0); // int(1000)
$intB = (int)($array['b'] ?? 0); // int(0)
$intC = (int)($array['c'] ?? 0) ?: null; // NULL

$stringA = (string)($array['a'] ?? ''); // string(4) "1000"
$stringB = (string)($array['b'] ?? ''); // string(0) ""
$stringC = (string)($array['a'] ?? '') ?: null; // string(4) "1000"
$stringD = (string)($array['d'] ?? '') ?: null; // NULL
$stringE = (isset($array['e']) ? (string)$array['e'] : null); // NULL

$arrayA = (array)($array['a'] ?? []); // [ 0 => int(1000) ]
$arrayB = (array)($array['b'] ?? []); // []
$arrayC = (array)($array['c'] ?? []) ?: null; // null

var_dump($boolA);
var_dump($boolB);
var_dump($boolC);

var_dump($intA);
var_dump($intB);
var_dump($intc);

var_dump($stringA);
var_dump($stringB);
var_dump($stringC);
var_dump($stringD);
var_dump($stringE);

var_dump($arrayA);
var_dump($arrayB);
var_dump($arrayC);
```

OUTPUT:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
NULL

int(1000)
int(0)
NULL

string(4) "1000"
string(0) ""
string(4) "1000"
NULL
NULL

array(1) {
  [0] => int(1000)
}
array(0) { }
NULL
```

Comment: why you're making default value null instead of expected value, like false, 0?

Comment: @YourCommonSense You're right, it's better to use expected values! I changed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could convert "falsey" values of the null-coalesced string typecast back to null.

```
$username = (string) ($inputs['username'] ?? '') ?: null;
```

It's kind of odd looking, but I think it would produce what you want without using `isset`. In this case, the `''` doesn't matter because it will never be used; it could be anything falsey.

Comment: This is the solution I've been using. It's very useful for checking truthy which means null, false, 0, "" wont get through. Must know what truthy does to not be caught out by this though!

Answer (score 1):

Old school:

```
<?php
$bar = null;
if(isset($foo))
    $bar = (string) $foo;
```

You could drop the null assignment:

```
isset($foo) && $bar = (string) $foo;
```

Comment: Can this be golfed to: `isset($foo) && $bar = "$foo";`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but it looks like you're casting in the wrong place.

You can do something like this:

```
$username = $inputs['username'] ?? null;

// cast $username to string 
if ($username && $username = (string) $username){
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, goal was to use `??` though in order to cut down on code, but doesn't seem it's possible to type cast in it.

Comment: Ahh.. I see..so you're trying to reduce the number of lines so your code looks elegant, yes? :)

Comment: More readable / elegant, yes, as this pattern is heavily used.

Comment: Tempting though it may seem, the problem with this kind of "elegance" is that sometimes it's not easily readable by the next guy. If the aim is to save two or three lines of space then I'd say it's probably not worth it. :)